# How not to use else main()?

Tags: c, if-statement

I'm writing this code:

```
int main()
{
    char text[SIZE], choice[SIZE];
    printf("\nWelcome to Caesar's Cipher.\nDo you wish to encrypt or decrypt text?\n");
    fgets(choice, SIZE, stdin);
    if (strcmp(choice, "encrypt\n") == 0)
    { 
        printf("\nInsert text to encrypt:\n");
        fgets(text, SIZE, stdin);
        ciphering(text);
        printf("\nThis is your text encrypted with Caesar's Cipher:\n%s\n", text);
    }
    else if (strncmp(choice, "decrypt", 7) == 0)
    { 
        printf("\nInsert text to decrypt:\n");
        fgets(text, SIZE, stdin);
        deciphering(text);
        printf("\nThis is your text encrypted with Caesar's Cipher:\n%s\n", text);
    }
    else main();
    return 0;
}
```

But the line else main() seems ugly and not correct. Should I change the code? If so, how? Or is that okay?

Comment: Please format this a little better; it's hard to read.  What is your program trying to do?

Comment: This is not very good style. You generally don't want to call `main()` explicitly. You are probably looking for a `while(1)` loop with a conditional break.

Comment: That's not a good idea anyway. If they user repeatedly enters options that aren't one of your selected commands, your program will eventually overflow its stack and likely crash.

Comment: Why are you prompting and reading which mode to use?  That's what command line arguments are for.  Rather than recursively calling main, print an error message and exit if the user enters an invalid mode.

Comment: @Teepeemm , I'm working on it. I'm doing a program that applies Caesar's cipher to input text. This is the main function. I also have two void functions that does the rest. Any suggestion?

Comment: @EdCottrell , any implementation suggestion?

Comment: @JasonR, should I remove the else condition then? If the user does not input one of the options should the program quits?

Comment: @bauer The answer by Evan Teran is very good. You want something like that, if not exactly that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should replace the recursive call to `main` with normal loop logic (`do{ } while(...)`, `while(...)`, `for(...)`, etc.

<strike>IIRC, calling `main` is considered ill-formed. So while the compiler may allow it, it is not something you are supposed to do.</strike>

If I were to convert your code to something more conventional (shooting for the same general behavior), I'd probably write this:

```
int main(void)
{
    while(1) {
        char text[SIZE], choice[SIZE];
        printf("\nWelcome to Caesar's Cipher.\nDo you wish to encrypt or decrypt text?\n");

        fgets(choice, SIZE, stdin);

        if (strcmp(choice, "encrypt\n") == 0)
        { 
            printf("\nInsert text to encrypt:\n");
            fgets(text, SIZE, stdin);
            ciphering(text);
            printf("\nThis is your text encrypted with Caesar's Cipher:\n%s\n", text);
            break;
        }
        else if (strncmp(choice, "decrypt", 7) == 0)
        { 
            printf("\nInsert text to decrypt:\n");
            fgets(text, SIZE, stdin);
            deciphering(text);
            printf("\nThis is your text encrypted with Caesar's Cipher:\n%s\n", text);
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You could also `goto`. If you dare.

Comment: @black, you kid but even a `goto` would be more idiomatic code than a recursive call to `main` :-P

Comment: @EvanTeran ,what does while(1) means? (I've started C not long ago...)

Comment: also it is possibly causing a stackoverflow if the user continuisly enter in that else condition.

Comment: Calling `main` is valid and not ill-formed in C (contratry to C++)

Comment: That's a little kinda like teaching OP "bad C manners". First of all, because those variables should be declared **prior** to everything else (I believe that although you might get around it in C99 or even in some other "forgiving" environment, a pure C compiler will emit an error for that). But more importantly, OP should at least implement the "interior" of those `if/else` statements in a separate function. That being said, I **do** realize that in terms of strictly answering the question at hand, the job is pretty much done here.

Comment: @bauer, it means "loop forever". Basically in C, any non-zero value when used in as a true/false condition is considered true (zero being false). So, it is saying "`while(TRUE)`"... which is always true :-)

Comment: @EvanTeran , therefore, your implementation allows to repeat the question but without possible memory issues caused by my bad implementation, correct?

Comment: @bauer, yes, it will continue to ask until good input is given.

Comment: @ouah, I assumed that C and C++ shared this rule, I stand corrected! Thanks :-)

Comment: @barakmanos aside from the fact that this code *does* declare variables before doing anything else, a "pure" C compiler *will not* emit an error for that; doing so would make the compiler nonconforming. Precisely because this has been allowed since C99. "Bad manners" is still teaching people that C89 == C. C89 has lost that claim.

Comment: @bauer it is bad practice here (and I don't think there is a case where it is a good practice) but it is valid

Comment: @ouah , okay, thanks. I actually feel that seemed wrong, that is why I wrote this post. However, in a first attempt, it worked. Now I've changed according with you guys. Thanks everybody :)

Answer (score 1):

It is much better to remove the recursion and write something like the following

```
int main( void )
{
    char text[SIZE], choice[SIZE];
    int valid_input = 0;

    do
    {
        printf("\nWelcome to Caesar's Cipher.\nDo you wish to encrypt or decrypt text?\n");
        fgets(choice, SIZE, stdin);
        if ( valid_input = ( strcmp(choice, "encrypt\n") == 0 ) )
        { 
            printf("\nInsert text to encrypt:\n");
            fgets(text, SIZE, stdin);
            ciphering(text);
            printf("\nThis is your text encrypted with Caesar's Cipher:\n%s\n", text);
        }
        else if ( valid_input = ( strncmp(choice, "decrypt", 7) == 0 ) )
        { 
            printf("\nInsert text to decrypt:\n");
            fgets(text, SIZE, stdin);
            deciphering(text);
            printf("\nThis is your text encrypted with Caesar's Cipher:\n%s\n", text);
        }
    } while ( !valid_input );

    return 0;
}
```

Variable valid_input also can be declared like

```
_Bool valid_input = 0;
```

Comment: what does the '!' in while ( !valid_input) means? And how does this works? I mean, what does it mean to declare int valid_input = 0? (I'm starting with C, I apologize for newbie questions)

Comment: @bauer, `!` means "NOT". So if `valid_input` is `0`, `!valid_input` is `1` and vice-versa. Based on this, you can read "while(!valid_input)" literally as "while NOT valid_input" which is due to good variable naming is self explanatory :-).

Comment: @bauer  It is a logical negation operator and means "not". You can read the condition like "while not valid input" That is until the user enters encrypt or decrypt the do-while loop will continue its iterations.

Comment: @EvanTeran , two doubts: 1. I'm trying to understand how does the program knows what valid input is. I mean, how does valid_input is evaluated? Looking for if statements implemented? ; 2. Why int main (void)? (why void inside?)

Comment: @bauer, these are kinda secondary questions which you want to ask separately. But I'll try. Unlike C++, in C, `int main()` is has a slightly differently meaning than `int main(void)`. The `(void)` version takes zero parameters, the `()`takes an unspecified number of parameters. In C++, they are equivalent. As for how the program know what is valid, well that's for you, the coder to decide! It will execute the conditions that YOU specify, so if YOU say valid_input is 0 (false), then the condition will go one way, if you set it to non-zero, it will go the other way. It'll all up to you.

Comment: @bauer The C Standard requires that main shall be declared like this (if it does not have parameters).  As for valid_input then it is set in each if statement. For example valid_input = ( strcmp(choice, "encrypt\n") == 0 ) . So if  strcmp(choice, "encrypt\n") == 0 then valid_input will be set to 1. otherwise to 0.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, as far as I understood, valid_input will be set to 0 if the conditions are True, is that correct? That's why you have declared int valid_input=0 , correct? Therefore, if valid_input=1 (different of zero), he will repeat the cycle, right?

Comment: @EvanTeran , then should I use int main (void) always? Or only if main function is not supposed to receive directly some input?

Comment: @bauer True corresponds to a non-zero value.  For example if the return value of function call strcmp(choice, "encrypt\n")  is equal to 0 then the value of expression strcmp(choice, "encrypt\n") == 0 equal to 1 and corresponds to True.

Comment: @bauer There are two standard declarations of main: with parameters and without parameters. main without parameters shall be declared as I showed.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow , but does not while ( !valid_input ) implies that valid_input assumes value 1? (because int valid_inupt=0). And if it assumes value 1, the cycle should not repeat.. What am I seeing wrong?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow , about the main (void) I think we're solved. Already get the idea. Thanks.

Comment: @bauer If input was not valid then valid_input is equal to 0. In this case its negation !valid_input is equal to 1 and the loop will be repeated until the user enteres either "encrypt" or "decrypt".

Comment: @VladfromMoscow , ok, thanks, got it after looking again to the code.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow , just one more thing. Is int valid_input forced to be initialized with value = 0 or it can be initialized with some other value?

Comment: @bauer It can be even uninitialized because within the loop it will be assigned a value in any case. However for readability it is better to initialize it with 0 because we start when the user entered nothing and it is supposed that the loop will continue until the valid input will be entered.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to move all of that code to a subroutine. The subroutine should return a value that indicates whether it succeeded or failed.

```
int choose( void )
{
    char text[SIZE], choice[SIZE];
    printf("\nWelcome to Caesar's Cipher.\nDo you wish to encrypt or decrypt text?\n");
    fgets(choice, SIZE, stdin);

    if (strcmp(choice, "encrypt\n") == 0)
    {
        printf("\nInsert text to encrypt:\n");
        fgets(text, SIZE, stdin);
        ciphering(text);
        printf("\nThis is your text encrypted with Caesar's Cipher:\n%s\n", text);
    }
    else if (strncmp(choice, "decrypt", 7) == 0)
    {
        printf("\nInsert text to decrypt:\n");
        fgets(text, SIZE, stdin);
        deciphering(text);
        printf("\nThis is your text encrypted with Caesar's Cipher:\n%s\n", text);
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }

    return 1;
}
```

Then have `main` call the subroutine until it succeeds:

```
int main( void )
{
    while ( !choose() )
        printf( "The choices are 'encrypt' or 'decrypt'\nPlease try again\n" );
    return 0;
}
```

Or have `main` print an error message if the function fails, and let the user start the program again if they want to:

```
int main( void )
{
    if ( !choose() )
        printf( "That was not a valid choice\n" );
    return 0;
}
```